# What apache VirtualHost configuration will serve one and only one domain over SSL?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I have multiple domains (`example1.com`, `example2.com`, `...`) hosted on the same IP. One of these domains (`example3.com`) has an SSL certificate and I want to serve it over HTTPS, while keeping all the other sites on HTTP. I have this set up and working correctly, so far.

My problem is that requests to `https://www.example1.com` (note the s) are getting handled by the apache configuration section for `example3.com` (which begins `<VirtualHost *:443>`), which causes problems as this is a Django site, and amongst other things it generates a 400 Bad Request due to `example1.com` not being in Django's `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting.

I understand that the nature of SSL means that the `Host:` header is not known until after the secure connection is established. But is there a way of getting apache to reject any requests over HTTPS that are *not* for `example3.com`?

I had expected use of the `ServerName` directive within the SSL Virtualhost to restrict that section to just the named host, but upon [closer inspection of the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) it seems that is only the case for name-based virtual hosts.

Edit: I have tried adding a catch-all default as the first section, like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName default.only
  <Location />
    Require all denied
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This causes the following error:

```
[Thu Dec 04 10:31:27.922801 2014] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10498:tid 3074255488] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 04 10:31:29.928483 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 30518:tid 3074300544] AH02240: Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)
[Thu Dec 04 10:31:29.928551 2014] [ssl:emerg] [pid 30518:tid 3074300544] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

Comment: You may try to add another config file `example1-ssl.conf` (for https example1.com) with `<VirtualHost *:443>` and `Require all denied` in the Directory section? httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html#run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you have posted indicate that you haven't included relevant necessary SSL configuration for your domains; for any domains/subdomains you wish to be accessible via SSL, you will need to provide relevant information for the certificate, etc, in the `VirtualHost` configuration(s) for the domains in question, eg:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com
    ServerName example1.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/example1certificate.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/example1privatekey.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/certificatechainfile.pem
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/certificateauthority.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

You will then need to create appropriate `VirtualHost` segments for the rest of your domains, but in these you will of course only configure the listen port to be 80, with no SSL configuration options, eg:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2.com
    ServerName example2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps!

PS, the above configurations for `SSLCipherSuite` and `SSLProtocol` are good - you can use them to save you time researching other possible configurations if you wish.

Comment: I did have these SSL configuration directives for my `https://example3.com` domain but not for the default domain. I have copied them across to the catch-all section and everything now works, though it doesn't feel right to be using a domain's SSL cert for a configuration section that doesn't apply to that domain.

Comment: You could always create a self-signed cert to satisfy the criteria for that specific domain whilst leaving the 'in-use' cert(s) for use on their own specific domains if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As @Polosson said in the comment, You'll need to create two port 443 virtual hosts to end up with this arrangement.

The first one you list will be the catch-all for anything ariving on port 443 -- this is implicit in listing it first. The second will be used whent he host is example3.com via ServerName.

Comment: Answer edited to show what I tried and the resulting error message.